# PHPmailer not working recipient

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a problem, with my code beneath I get this error message:
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: !Censored!

I have looked into the Host, Port, Username, Password, Recipient and all is correct, what is the problem? Thank you!

Could you please explain too cuz Im new to PHP-coding

```
 <?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['amne'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '!Censored!';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '!Censored!';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '!Censored!';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->addAddress('!Censored!');     // Add a recipient

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

EDIT: I found the problem, the problem was not in the php code itself. It was in the contact form. The problem started when I put the variables as names and emails. If the email is not verified, it does not work.

Comment: Since you don't want to show the email, username, and password (which is fine, btw), could you double-check that they're correct, just to make sure that the problem is with the code itself?

Comment: Try to set $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  to $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

Comment: No, don't switch to `tls`. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` and you will see the SMTP transcript which will probably tell you what's wrong. You should also read [the troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: Hey, I get this problem now: `2015-03-17 20:22:47 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-03-17 20:22:47 SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.` But the port my host is using is 587, so I dont know what the problem is, I have copy-pasted the host and port so I dont think its anything wrong with that. I also changed 'tls' to 'ssh' but with no success

Comment: Hey, when I changed it back to 'tls' this showed up: `Recipient address rejected: Access denied 2015-03-17 20:28:31 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 450 4.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access denied 2015-03-17 20:28:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-03-17 20:28:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye 2015-03-17 20:28:31`

Answer (score 2):

This error can be caused by a few different things. You can get a better idea of the reason by adding the following line to your PHPMailer script:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //<-- For debugging
```

Once you do that, you can check the following things that may be causing the error:

1.) A corrupt class.phpmailer.php file.

2.) The error may be caused by protection put in place by your ISP. Check with them.

3.) It could be a problem with the recipient's/sender's email addresses.

4.) Set SMTPAuth to true for PHPMailer class.

5.) Comment out the following line in your PHPMailer script: $mail->isSMTP();

Mostly, There is possibility that Your `phpmailer` class file is corrupted.

Download the latest version: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Commenting out `isSMTP` is not a fix, it's just moving the problem.

Comment: Hey, I have dont SMTPDebug 2, and  I get this error message: `2015-03-17 20:22:47 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-03-17 20:22:47 SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.` Both my port and host is correct, so I dont know what the problem is...

Comment: When I changed it back to 'tls' this popped up: `Recipient address rejected: Access denied 2015-03-17 20:28:31 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 450 4.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access denied 2015-03-17 20:28:31 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2015-03-17 20:28:31 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye 2015-03-17 20:28:31`